# Extending `git-p4` clientspec after initial clone

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

After doing a `git-p4 clone --use-clientspec`, I would like to add an extra entry to the clientspec, and import the current state of the added entry to my Git repository.

After I extend the clientspec, a `git-p4 rebase` does nothing (probably because there was no new relevant changelist since the last committed change, all I did was update the clientspec)

I tried doing a `git-p4 sync --use-client-spec`, but this complains that fast-import failed because the new tip does not contain my initial commit.

Is there a way to extend the client spec, without having to `git-p4 clone` a new Git repository from scratch?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781449/git-p4-clone-sync-how-to-add-new-p4-path , although I'm not convinced that the answer there works (it didn't work for me, and it apparently doesn't work for you either).

Comment: @jamesdlin, I agree the other one suffers the issue you pointed out, while your answer here does noit.

Answer (score 4):

As of writing, I could not find a way to get `git-p4` to import additional paths from a Perforce clientspec directly.  However, I believe that I've devised a way to manually do it and have `git-p4` honor it.

**Disclaimer:** I take no responsibility for any damage that the following steps might cause.  It probably would be a good idea to back up your `.git` tree first.

## The idea

As you say, just adding a path to the Perforce clientspec and doing a `git p4 rebase` initially does not do anything.  However, I noticed that `git p4 rebase` will add files from that path after they are modified in Perforce and if the new path is within `git-p4`'s `depot-paths` list. (`depot-paths` is the initial list of depot paths provided to `git p4 clone`.) Therefore you need:

1. To get an initial copy of the new path into your Git repository.
2. To trick `git-p4` into believing that it added that initial copy itself.
3. To get `git-p4` to include the new path in its `depot-paths` list.

Thus you can sync a copy of the files from Perforce, making sure that they're consistent with the files already imported from Perforce, and then you can explicitly add them to your Git repository.

`git-p4` apparently does not store its `depot-paths` list nor the last imported Perforce change number anywhere other than in Git commit messages, so you can trick `git-p4` by replicating its metadata in your own commit message.

Finally, you can move `p4/master` (and `p4/HEAD`, which is an alias to `p4/master`) to point to your new commit so that future `git p4 rebase` commands treat that commit as something imported from Perforce.

## Step by step

1. Check out the commit corresponding to `p4/master`.  Make sure that you don't have any staged or unstaged changes.  Stash them if you do.
2. Add the new path to the Perforce clientspec used by `git-p4`.  In the steps below, I'll refer to this as `//depot/new/path/`.
3. Run `git log` to look at the commit message from the Perforce change you last imported.  It will have a line that looks like:

   `[git-p4: depot-paths = "//depot/tree/": change = 12345]`

   Make a note of the Perforce change number.
4. In your Perforce client, sync your added path to that change number.  For example: `p4 sync //depot/new/path/...@12345`
5. Recursively copy those newly synced files from your Perforce client into the corresponding location in your Git repository. (Some care might be needed here if there are symlinks.)
6. Run `git add` on that new path in your Git repository.
7. Run `git commit`.  You can mostly say whatever you want in your commit message (e.g. "Initial import of //depot/new/path/ from CLN 12345").  However, at the end of the message you must copy the `git-p4` metadata line that you observed before:

   `[git-p4: depot-paths = "//depot/tree/": change = 12345]`

   If `//depot/new/path/` is not a subdirectory of `//depot/tree`, then you must amend `depot-paths` to add the new path:

   `[git-p4: depot-paths = "//depot/new/path/,//depot/tree/": change = 12345]`

   The `depot-paths` list *must be sorted* by ASCII value (i.e., `//depot/foo-bar/` should precede `//depot/foo/bar/`).
8. Run `git log` again.  Confirm that the `git-p4` line in the commit message looks like ones from imported Perforce changes.  Make a note of the SHA1 hash of your commit.
9. Navigate to the root of your Git repository.  Edit `.git/refs/remotes/p4/master`.  Remove the old SHA1 hash listed and replace it with the SHA1 hash of your commit. (If `.git/refs/remotes/p4/master` does not exist, check `.git/packed-refs` and update the appropriate line there.)

Now your Git repository includes a copy of the files from `//depot/new/path/` from change 12345, and it should pick up any changes to those files from future Perforce changes.

## Some other things of note

- Obviously the new path will exist in your Git repository only after your commit that imported those files, so `git bisect` won't be useful if it straddles that boundary and involves those files.
- Since modified files get automatically added if they're included in your Perforce clientspec (and are contained within `git-p4`'s `depot-paths`), in some cases you potentially could avoid all of this work.  For example, if you know in advance that someone is going to be adding a new directory to the Perforce depot and that directory is already included by your `depot-paths` but not by your clientspec, you can just preemptively add it to your Perforce clientspec.  You then should be able to get that new path automatically after it's actually added to Perforce.
- Alternatively you could add the new path to your Perforce clientspec and then submit a Perforce change that touches all of the files in that path.  I do *not* recommend doing that, however, as that could be disruptive to others (and imagine if everyone else did that).  I mention it only for completeness.

Comment: This worked for me. I might have had to do my own `git rebase -i` to rebase my commits on top of the commits that are imports from p4, because the first time I did `git p4 rebase` after following the steps in this answer, my commits did not get automatically rebased onto the newly imported commits from p4.
If you do your own `git rebase -i`, then make sure to check and edit `.git/refs/remotes/p4/master` after doing `git rebase -i`.

Comment: A different SO question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175539/git-clone-multiple-p4-paths-in-one-git-repo approches the problem from a different angle that feels clean to me. However that method failed for me due to crlf issues, probably due to my use of cygwin with a binary mount point.  @jamesdlin's method did not experience the same crlf issue.

Answer (score 1):

@jamesdlin's answer is what worked for me. While researching ideas for how to solve this, I came across a couple other stackoverflow answers that were interesting. I wonder if they could be combined to create an elegant solution. I'm mentioning the idea here in case it helps someone else. This idea is a variation of what's described in [How to copy commits from one Git repo to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471740/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-git-repo-to-another) and borrows an idea from [git clone multiple p4 paths in one git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175539/git-clone-multiple-p4-paths-in-one-git-repo).

1. Start with p4 client Pa, which is mirrored into git repo Ga.  Take the set of paths that you add to client Pa, and create a new p4 client Pb that maps only those paths.
2. Next create a new git repo Gb that clones p4 client Pb. The git repo Gb can be created in a any temporary location, and it will be thrown away when done. `git p4 clone newstuff ...etc...`
3. Back in Ga, add a new remote to Gb. `git remote add newstuff /path/to/newstuff`
4. Follow the remaining instructions from [How to copy commits from one Git repo to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471740/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-git-repo-to-another).  Use cherry-pick like in those instructions. Or use `git merge`, with `--allow-unrelated-histories` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

[JeffJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5429/jeffj) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376692/extending-git-p4-clientspec-after-initial-clone#comment96239106_30279082) to an alternative approach using "[`git clone` multiple p4 paths in one git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50029650/6309)":

> cloning different Perforce paths into different Git repositories and later merge them into a new repository while keeping the history.

However, JeffJ adds:

> However that method failed for me due to crlf issues, probably due to my use of cygwin with a binary mount point.

That should no longer be the case: `git p4` working on UTF-16 files on Windows did not implement CRLF-to-LF conversion correctly, but it has been corrected with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022).

See [commit 4d35f74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d35f744219335d8b32df363891b6336dcf02a6e) (20 Jul 2022) by [Moritz Baumann (`mbs-c`)](https://github.com/mbs-c).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 745af8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/745af8c7b5506f17516e21629386191acb26aae7), 27 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d35f744219335d8b32df363891b6336dcf02a6e): fix CR LF handling for utf16 files
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Moritz Baumann</sup>

> Perforce silently replaces LF with CR LF for "utf16" files if the client is a native Windows client.
> Since git's autocrlf logic does not undo this transformation for UTF-16 encoded files, `git-p4` replaces CR LF with LF during the sync if the file type "utf16" is detected and the Perforce client platform indicates that this conversion is performed.
>
> Windows only runs on little-endian architectures, therefore the encoding of the byte stream received from the Perforce client is UTF-16-LE and the relevant byte sequence is `0D 00 0A 0`0.