# How to handle git-p4 with special workspace mapping

Tags: perforce, git-p4

I'm trying to make a git repo that I can push master to perforce. I'm thinking useing git+gitflow and rebase into master to update upstream. This is to increase collaboration between developers on expreimental branches and to still have a way to push it to head in perforce.

I'n my workspace i have a workspace mapping that looks like this:

```
//app/... //workspace/...
//api/... //workspace/include/...
//frontend-tests/... //workspace/tests/frontend/...
```

I have tried doing the following:

```
git p4 clone //app .
git p4 clone //api ./include
git p4 clone //frontend-tests ./tests/frontend
```

Now this gives me 3 git repo which I'll have to syn with perforce independently. Is there a way to get just one git repo?

Is there a way to do this where I end up with one git repository?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30279694/179715

Comment: @jamesdlin Actually following it and using the `--use-client-spec` worked. It even linked to how to add more paths, something I have been wondering about too.